# How can I run a Flutter application on older iOS versions without upgrading sdk to iOS 17.4?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have an iOS simulator for version 17.2 installed on my Mac. I was able to successfully run the flutter app before I upgraded to the latest Flutter version, and it now requires me to download iOS 17.4. Since the file size is very large, I want to avoid it if possible. Are there any ways to run a flutter application on older iOS versions?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            1.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { id:(hid it just in case) }

    Ineligible destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device, error:iOS 17.4 is not installed. To use with Xcode, first download and install the platform }

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
iOS 17.4 is not installed. To download and install the platform, open
Xcode, select Xcode > Settings > Platforms, and click the GET button for the
required platform.

For more information, please visit:
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
```

I've searched for an hour and tried looking into the Runner settings but couldn't find how to change the target build version.

[My Xcode Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfbWC.jpg)

Comment: Xcode has probably updated.  You can see if you can create a simulator in Xcode that uses iOS 17.2 and use that as your target or you can download the 17.4 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

open `runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode and change your minimum deployment target as your requirement

Comment: I've set the iOS Deployment Target to 12.0 but it still won't work.

Comment: see your error you have to select device and run destination can you share pic of your Xcode interface

Comment: I'm already using iOS  17.2  and updated flutter to newest version just now you can try deleting your build folder and and running again with xcworkspace

Comment: I've edited my post to include a screenshot of the Xcode interface. I tried deleting my build folder and starting debug session again, but it yielded the same error.

Comment: see in the screenshot you shared I think u by mistake upgraded your macOS or Xcode that's why it's asking for update to simulator iOS 17.4

Comment: what's showing when you click on manage run destination ?

Comment: I couldn't find any option that allowed me to debug the app on iOS 17.2. And yes, Xcode automatically updated, and I also upgraded Flutter to try to solve another bug, so that's probably why. I've updated my simulator to iOS 17.4, which now works completely fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any option to run a Flutter application on older iOS versions without upgrading SDK to iOS 17.4. It is caused by upgrading your Flutter SDK.